# seperate same category input data from view form in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

when form field is fixed like

```
<form name="" action="">
     <input type="text" name="username">
     <input type="text" name="password">
     <input type="email" name="email">
     <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

then we collect data from this from using
`$input_data = Input::all();`  this code and insert into particular username and email field in database

but

if form will be like

```
<form name="" action="">
     <input type="text" name="username">
     <input type="text" name="password">
     <input type="email" name="email">
     <input type="email" name="email_1">
     <input type="email" name="email_2">
     <input type="email" name="email_3">
                   ......
                   ......
                   ......
                   ......
     <input type="email" name="email_15">

     <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

then 
in controller `$input_data = Input::all();`
get the all value but my specific question is how to separate all emails and username,password value

my db structure is   `[ username, password, emails ]`    i want to save all emails in emails field

NB:  emails are dynamically added form by javascript.so all time total email number is not same

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure I understand what you are asking and also not familiar with Laravel, but if you are trying to make it easier on yourself with multiple form inputs of the same type without having to worry about unique names, try using array fields:

```
<form name="" action="">
     <input type="text" name="username">
     <input type="text" name="password">
     <input type="email" name="email[]">
     <input type="email" name="email[]">
     <input type="email" name="email[]">
     <input type="email" name="email[]">
     <input type="email" name="email[]">
     <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

It will just come out as a single email array that you can easily iterate through with a foreach. If you are trying to save a series of emails into one column, you can `implode()` the email array (though storing a bunch of emails in a comma separated string in one column is probably not the best idea).

Anyway, I am not sure if this helps at all...you may need to clarify if what I am saying is off-base.